# Is docker best just for prod environments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, microservices, aws-fargate

I just decided to jump into using docker to test out building a microservice application using AWS fargate.

My question really relates to hearing about many development teams using Docker to avoid people saying the phrase "works on my machine" when committing code. Although I see the solution to that problem being solved, I still do not see how Docker images actually can be used in development environment.

The workflow for anything above production baffles me. Example of my thinking is...

***team of 10 devs all use docker, each pull the image from the repo to there container, with the source code, if they all have a individual version of the image, that means any edits they make to that image is their own and when they push back to the repo where none of the edits can be merged (along with that to edit a image source code is not easily done as well).***

I am thinking of it in the say way as git -GitHub, where code is pushed to a branch and then merged to master to create a finished product.

I guess if you pull the code from the GitHub master and create the Docker image is the way for it to be used, but again that points back to my original assumption of Docker being used for Production environments over development.

Is docker being used in development, more so the dev can just test the feature on the container that ever other dev on the team is using so all the environments match across the team?

I just really do not understand the workflow of development environments with docker.

Comment: vs-code dev containers dose a good job in solving the "works on my machine" problem https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-tutorial - though getting some devs to stop using notepad++ and full local install over clicking a button is harder than it sounds

Comment: @LawrenceCherone notepad++ would be a step up from, some of the teams I worked with where it seems `vim` was the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd highlight three cases where I've found Docker particularly useful, prior to a production deploy:

1. Docker is really useful for installing **local dependencies**.  If your application needs a database, `docker run postgresql` with appropriate options.  Need a clean start?  Delete the container.  Running two microservices that need separate databases?  Start two containers.  The second microservice is maintained by another team?  Run it in a container too.
2. Docker is useful for **capturing the build environment in the CI system**.  Jenkins, for example, can run build steps inside a container, bind-mounting the current work tree in, so it's useful to build an image that just contains build-time dependencies (which can be updated independently of the CI system itself).
3. If you're running Docker in production, you can **test the exact thing you're about to run**.  You're guaranteed the install environment will be the same in the QA and prod environments, because it's encapsulated inside the same Docker image.  A developer can debug problems against the production-installed code without actually being in production.

In the basic scenario you describe, an important detail to note is that you never "edit an image"; you always `docker build` a new image from its Dockerfile and other source code.  In compiled languages (C++, Go, Java, Rust, Haskell) the source code won't be in the image.  Even if you're "using Docker in development" the actual source code will be in some other system (frequently Git), and typically you will have a CI system that builds "official" images from that source code.

Where I see Docker proposed for day-to-day development, it's either because the language ecosystem in use makes it hard to have multiple versions concurrently installed, or to avoid installing software on the host system.  You need specific tooling support to "develop inside a container", and if developers choose their own IDE, this support is not universal.  Conversely, in between OS package managers (APT, Homebrew) and interpreter version managers (rbenv, nvm) it's usually straightforward to install a couple of things on the host.  If your application isn't that sensitive to, say, the specific version of Node, it's probably easier to use whichever version is already installed on your host than to try to insert Docker into the process.